# Delete Windows-RE partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

After an upgrade to Windows 8.1 in my dual boot system with Arch Linux, my Partition Table contains three partitions of type "Windows RE" (numbers 1, 6 and 11, see the output of gdisk -l /dev/sda under linux)

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2050047   1000.0 MiB  2700  Basic data partition
   2         2050048         2582527   260.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         2582528         4630527   1000.0 MiB  ED01  Basic data partition
   4         4630528         4892671   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   5         4892672       238346071   111.3 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   6       238346240       239267839   450.0 MiB   2700  
   7       239267840       317392895   37.3 GiB    8300  ARCH
   8       317392896       340830207   11.2 GiB    8200  
   9       340830208      1859151871   724.0 GiB   0700  
  10      1859151872      1911580671   25.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
  11      1911580672      1953523711   20.0 GiB    2700  Basic data partition
```

Is it safe to make a backup and then remove them from disk?
Or should I just start from scratch with a new Windows installation, as my partition table is really filled with things I don't need at all?

Comment: Comparing with my system, it seems that partitions 1-4 and the last two are used for Windows boot/recovery. Why so many are needed is beyond me. You can always mount them and see what's in them. An Ubuntu LiveCD has `gnome-disks` and `gparted`, which are both very useful for examining/mounting partitions and copying/resizing/moving them.

Comment: That's a good idea - I'm going to look into them and post here - but anyway, I think I'm going with a clean reinstall, also, because all this Lenovo bloatware makes me really upset.

Comment: I don't know how much of the recovery is due to Windows and how much to Lenovo. I guess the second-last (labelled LENOVO) allows the recovery of their add-ons, but since the drivers may be on it I've kept it, along with the other partitions, though whenever I try to boot Windows (installed or recovery) I get EFI errors.